# Getting error error: [Transaction]: Error: No valid responses from any peers. Errors: while submit transaction in hyperledger fabric 2.2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have deploy HLF 2.2 fabric-sample's  test-network on AWS ec2 instance.
Now I have created connection.json file to connect to network. now things that I can easily connect to org CA, but when I am trying to submit transaction I am getting error. as below

```
 error: [Transaction]: Error: No valid responses from any peers. Errors:
```

I am trying to connect from local machine to AWS EC2 instance and all port is open on AWS instance still facing error.
Anybody help me to solve issue

My connection profile file

```
{
    "name": "test-network-org2",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Org2",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org2": {
            "mspid": "Org2MSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer0.org2.example.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.org2.example.com"
            ]
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org2.example.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://ec2-19-219-120-22.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9051",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nFe94PjvXFGF4djPSyrSbhVcK\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org2.example.com",
                "hostnameOverride": "peer0.org2.example.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.org2.example.com": {
            "url": "https://ec2-19-219-120-22.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8054",
            "caName": "ca-org2",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": ["-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nFe94PjvXFGF4djPSyrSbhVcK\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"]
            },
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the entire error message?  Nothing after "Errors:"?

Comment: sorry@GariSingh this was issue of my blockchain setup